# XDocReport can't display two image in generated document

Tags: java, velocity, xdocreport

I insert two image to template: "logo" and "background"
But only background image presented in template.

I create ImageProdiver

```
private IImageProvider createImageProvider(IXDocReport ixDocReport, String fieldName, Blob image) {
    FieldsMetadata metadata = ixDocReport.createFieldsMetadata();
    metadata.addFieldAsImage( fieldName);
    ixDocReport.setFieldsMetadata(metadata);
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = image.getBinaryStream();
        IImageProvider logo = new ByteArrayImageProvider(inputStream);
        logo.setUseImageSize(true);
        logo.setResize(true);
        inputStream.close();
        return logo;
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        throw new GeneralException("Error reading logo");
    } finally {
        if(inputStream != null) {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Create two Image provider

```
IImageProvider logo = createImageProdider(report, "logo", blobimage));
IImageProvider background = createImageProdider(report, "logo", blobimagebacground));
```

and insert to context in builder

```
context = this.report.createContext();
context.put("logo", logo);
context.put("background", background);
```

after generate document, exist only background image.

I do not understand why there is this problem, why only one picture is displayed.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you set FieldsMetadata to report two times.
You need to create one FieldsMetadata metadata = ixDocReport.createFieldsMetadata()  and add two image to it.
Foe example:

```
 FieldsMetadata metadata = new FieldsMetadata();
 metadata.addFieldAsImage("chart1");
 metadata.addFieldAsImage("chart2");
 report.setFieldsMetadata(metadata);

 IImageProvider logo = new FileImageProvider(new File("path/to/image1"), true);
 context.put("chart1", logo);

 IImageProvider logo2 = new FileImageProvider(new File("path/to/image2"), true);
 context.put("chart2", logo2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!